# vim shortcut to replace char under cursor with an expression?

Tags: vim, latex

I'm processing an old text into latex.

All I have is an old pdf file, which I copy-paste bit by bit, replacing the ill-copied bits to fit latex code. The text contains a lot of inline math, and features a lot of different variables. Every variable is explained in-text and is thus named inline:

```
Zie figuur 3, waar R de weerstand voorstelt
```

What I do now is this:

1. go to the relevant line
2. in normal mode type <kbd>f</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (where `R` is the char I need to change)
3. <kbd>i</kbd>
4. type `\(` before the char
5. type `\)`after the char

voila, the char is now recognized by latex as a math char.

I would like to now if there isn't a quicker procedure that replaces steps 3 to 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record a macro. For example, if you want to save it in register *a* do the following:

```
fRqai\(<esc>la\)<esc>q
```

Now, once you're over the character you want, use `@a`. To repeat the last macro you can also use `@@`. So, an example of redoing it:

```
fR@a
```

Comment: Yep, then you can create a map. Save a line like this in your vimrc: `nnoremap ,d i\(<esc>la\)<esc>` (using whatever shortcut you prefer over `,d`) and then just use it instead of the macro. And thanks for the edit, didn't notice the lack of an esc :-)